# Drag images to droppable and record individual image name

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and would like to know if the following is possible!

I have an array of images in php which I would like to display in a specific area. From here I would like to drag individual images to a droppable area and record the image name (path) to another php array.

I have experimented by creating an image, and have been able to drag it to a droppable area using clone() which works successfully. However this only seems to work within a "div" tag and does not record the filename. Also my array can vary in size and image sources, if this cannot be achieved in JQuery what else could I look at?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the jquery UI library on the following link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager